# DFS | The Network Path was not found | RPC Server is unavailable

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2016, windows-10, dfs

Suddenly we got a problem on some windows pcs when accessing the dfs share. Before this the DFS access was working.

**The Problem**
*Some* clients suddenly cannot access the dfs share like: `\\thedomain\dfs`

Error: **The Network Path was not found**

`\\thedomain.local\dfs` resolves, but doesn't work either

**When it starts happening**
It *seems* to happen on clients which were rebooted.

**What happened before**
An Exchange 2007 was uninstalled from one of the domain controllers.

**Environment**

- Server 2008 (10.15.24.9) (domain controller; formerly sbs2008)
- Server 2016 (10.15.24.8) (dfs server)
- Windows 10 / Windows 7 Clients

**We already checked**

- works on most pcs: \thedomain.local\dfs
- works on most pcs: \thedomain\dfs
- works: net view \\10.15.24.8
- works: nslookup thedomain.local
- works: Access via IP \\10.15.24.8\dfs
- **fails:** dfsdiag /testdfsconfig /dfsroot:\\thedomain.**local**\dfs

  - result: RPC Server is unavailable
- works: dfsdiag /testdfsconfig /dfsroot:\\thedomain\dfs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting the service "**dfs-namespace**" on the domain controller solved the problem.